# SWIG_csharp_string_callback leads to a memory leak when passing a string (const char*) from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks, swig

I'm facing a memory leak when passing string (const char*) arguments from C++ to C# using swig directors. I found a similar [question](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/Leaky-SWIG-csharp-string-callback-td11810.html) in swig forums with some valuable advices, however, the set of correct typemaps were missing (the issue is unresolved even in the current swig version 2.0.11).

After spending several days of googling and investigating the swig code I finally wrote a set of typemaps which fixed the problem for me.

I hope this question and posted answer will be helpful.

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why this would happen, I have passed strings between C# and C++ using swig in a large application and never observed memory leaks (well there were some leaks at some point but not due to this). Sounds like you found a solution so that's good.

Comment: Quoting from [swig forum](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/Leaky-SWIG-csharp-string-callback-td11810.html): 
If a C# callback returns a managed string to C (which happens in SWIG_csharp_string_callback method), it seems to reason that .Net or Mono would allocate an unmanaged string and return it to the native code, because otherwise the returned value - if it was actually pointing to the managed object would need to be pinned, but that is not happening. Hence, this freshly allocated memory is not being cleaned which probably leads to a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the set of typemaps for char* which did the job for me.

The idea is to pass char* as an IntPtr to C# then convert it into a C# string using `InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi()` (The C# string will be destroyed by GC). Similarly, when passing a string from C# to C++ we convert it into an IntPtr with `InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi()` method (and ensure that the object will be finally destroyed once the call returns).

```
// Alternative char * typemaps.
%pragma(csharp) imclasscode=%{
  public class SWIGStringMarshal : IDisposable {
    public readonly HandleRef swigCPtr;
    public SWIGStringMarshal(string str) {
      swigCPtr = new HandleRef(this, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(str));
    }
    public virtual void Dispose() {
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(swigCPtr.Handle);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~SWIGStringMarshal()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
  }
%}

%typemap(ctype) char* "char *"
%typemap(cstype) char* "string"
// Passing char* as an IntPtr to C# and then convert it to a C# string.
%typemap(imtype, out="IntPtr") char *  "HandleRef"

%typemap(in) char* %{$1 = ($1_ltype)$input; %}
%typemap(out) char* %{$result = $1; %}

%typemap(csin) char* "new $imclassname.SWIGStringMarshal($csinput).swigCPtr"
%typemap(csout, excode=SWIGEXCODE) char *{
    string ret = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi($imcall);$excode
    return ret;
}
%typemap(csvarin, excode=SWIGEXCODE2) char * %{
    set {
        $imcall;$excode
} %}

%typemap(csvarout, excode=SWIGEXCODE2) char * %{
    get {
        string ret = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi($imcall);$excode
        return ret;
} %}

%typemap(directorout) char* %{$result = ($1_ltype)$input; %}
%typemap(csdirectorout) char * "$cscall"

%typemap(directorin) char * 
%{
    $input = (char*)$1;
%}
%typemap(csdirectorin) char* "System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi($iminput)";
```

ps. I tested the typemaps on Windows 32/64 as well as on Linux 64 operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, an it has been reported years ago in SWIG org, see
https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/283 and
https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/998

This bug has not been fixed in latest version (until now is version 4.0.2).

The bug of the code is in swig\Lib\csharp\std_string.i. With the bug, when there is callback with string, it generates function like this in C++ in my application:

```
void SwigDirector_MyCode::LogDebug(std::string const &message) {
  char * jmessage = 0 ;
  if (!swig_callbackLogDebug) {
    throw Swig::DirectorPureVirtualException("SDS::ISDSLogger::LogDebug");
  } else {
    jmessage = SWIG_csharp_string_callback((&message)->c_str());
    swig_callbackLogDebug(jmessage);
  }
}
```

The LogDebug shall be called from C++ code.

In the code, the jmessage is new allocated memory. You can verify it you change the first char in the jmessage after the call, and you can see the (&message)->c_str() is not changed.

There are ideas saying that the free() or delete shall be called to deallocate the memory created from SWIG_csharp_string_callback().

But this is not working for me. I am using SWIG to generate C# wrapper from C++.

My solution is to define new typemap for the type std::string const & in my project .i file.

```
%typemap(directorin) const std::string & %{ $input = const_cast<char *>($1.c_str()); %}
```

So my generated code becomes:

```
void SwigDirector_MyCode::LogDebug(std::string const &message) {
  char * jmessage = 0 ;

  if (!swig_callbackLogDebug) {
    throw Swig::DirectorPureVirtualException("MyCode::LogDebug");
  } else {
    jmessage = const_cast<char *>((&message)->c_str()); 
    swig_callbackLogDebug(jmessage);
  }
}
```

In this code, jmessage is not allocated anymore.

It has been tested on Debian 9 mono and Windows 7 with VS2017.